# How to install a ceiling lamp that doesn't have holes

Tags: ceiling, lamp

I bought a floating lamp,

I started building everything, when I noted that the holder doesn't had any holes to fix it on the roof.

This are the "instructions":
[image: Instructions]

Here you can see my issue :(
[image: Full view]

This is a close up to the PLASTIC holder, only a small hole which is to keep a cable floating
[image: Close up of the holder]

This is a picture from the inside of the holder
[image: Inside the holder]

This is the hole of the cables:
[image: cable holes]

Comment: The bracket that bolts across the electrical box....it is different than the usual flat type bracket. Does it's length match to the inside diameter of the cone top? If so maybe the ridge of the cone top is meant to snap over the very ends if the bracket? To work the bracket would not be able to pull up in the hole and would have to sit against the ceiling surface.

Comment: It's a regular plane bracket, it's smaller than the lenght of the top of the cone, so I can't snap it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take up the cable to the right length using the bracket in your last picture. Then you can pull the conical cover up. When I've used these, there's always been either (i) a little plastic screw in the hole you can see at the bottom of picture 3 or (ii) some form of friction clip built into the point of the cone.

Comment: I think the cord is running backwards though the bracket, too - the supporting cable should be a straight drop from the bracket. As shown in the instructions, which were not followed...

Comment: @Ecnerwal it didn't look right to me either (on a small screen).

Comment: Thanks! it was the small plastic screw, it doesn't actually hold to the roof or ceiling but to the cable in that height

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to your question but rather an observation that requires some attention.

[image]

The three areas highlighted are not legitimate electrical connections.

Comment: Thanks Miachael!, I did realized of that, it was really hard to find which one was the live, all that was like that when I opend it up, it's some kind of extension or something that the owner of the building did.

But all the cables are the same exact color!